# How to use a ribbon which relies on VBa in a new Excel instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have some VBa which I run quite often. To make my life easier, I've added a new group to the ribbon and added a "button". I did this by clicking `File` -> `Options` and then `Customise Ribbon`. From the `choose commands from` I chose Macro and in the list was my macro. This is what I dragged into the new group in the ribbon

[image]

When I click on the button, it does what I expect.

The problem occurs when attempt this on a new workbook. If I close all Excel and open a new Excel instance I can see the new `Custom Features` in the ribbon. When I click on the button it fails with the following message

> Cannot run the macro 'Book1!PasteFromWebsite'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

I understand the error message but not how I can fix it or assign the macro to the button so this becomes always available on all Excel instances.

Comment: where is your macro located? It should be in a workbook which opens automatically with Excel.

Comment: The macro appears to only exist in the workbook where it was created @MátéJuhász . if this is not expected, I can try it again

Comment: yes, it exists only in the workbook where it's created, however if that workbook is open, then you can call it from any other open workbook.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, does that mean the functionality I'm after doesn't exist (using VBa)?

Comment: Try to use `Store Common Macros in the Personal Macro Workbook` <https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013097_Store_Common_Macros_in_the_Personal_Macro_Workbook.html>